# How to retrieve Workbook from Document Library View Using C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I need to fetch , read and update workbooks present in **document library** view. 
I am trying to use CSOM for same sa I am building app in C#. 
I am able to generate client token and also get documents using (TokenHelper)

```
FileCollection files = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderName).Files
```

But i have two issues 
1 : How to get documents from particular view as above method gives all documents .
2 : When I try to open documen using below code I am getting exception .

```
FileInformation fileInformation = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(context, (string)f.ServerRelativeUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use EPPLUS to read excel file.

Sample code:

```
 File file = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/Shared%20Documents/testdata.xlsx");
                ClientResult<System.IO.Stream> data=file.OpenBinaryStream();
                clientContext.Load(file);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                using (var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
                {
                    //using (var stream = File.OpenRead(""))
                    //{
                    //    pck.Load(stream);
                    //}
                    using (System.IO.MemoryStream mStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                    {
                        if (data != null)
                        {
                            data.Value.CopyTo(mStream);
                            pck.Load(mStream);
                            var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
                            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
                            bool hasHeader = true; // adjust it accordingly( i've mentioned that this is a simple approach)
                            foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
                            {
                                tbl.Columns.Add(hasHeader ? firstRowCell.Text : string.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column));
                            }
                            var startRow = hasHeader ? 2 : 1;
                            for (var rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
                            {
                                var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, ws.Dimension.End.Column];
                                var row = tbl.NewRow();
                                foreach (var cell in wsRow)
                                {
                                    if (null != cell.Hyperlink)
                                        row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Hyperlink;
                                    else
                                        row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
                                }
                                tbl.Rows.Add(row);
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine('1');

                        }
                    }



                }
```